# Submit Otp Without Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

i want to Click on the Submit That Send Otp to my Phone or Email 
im not Really Familiar With Ajax Can any one Explain how to do it on this Html :

```
<input type="submit" value="OTP code " name="Otp" id="Otp" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is to use `jQuery.ajax`. If you aren't familiar with jQuery, jQuery is a JavaScript framework that makes JavaScript coding much easier and faster, especially for beginners.

More information about jQuery.ajax: [jQuery.ajax() by jQuery.com](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$('#Opt').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'target.php',
        success: function(data){
            //any code to handle "data" received from target.php
        }
    });
});
```

What we did in this example, is:

- selecting the button element by the ID name - `$('#Opt')`
- adding "click" event to the button - `on('click', function...`
- preventing the form to submit and refresh the page - `e.PreventDefault()`
- using jQuery ajax function to send request to target.php - `$.ajax({...`
- setting up ajax options, for example, target page by using `url: 'target.php'`
- creating a function which will handle the response - `success: function(){...`

In the success function you should add any code that you want to run as soon as the request is finished successfully. the `data` var will contain the response from the server (in this case, the `target.php` response).

Comment: Okay it Work Somehow The Page Didnt Refresh But it didnt Send the otp Code to my email

Comment: @csgomovie in order to send something to your email you should use a server-side code (using PHP for example) to handle data from your form and send it to your email. You should start learning about PHP or any similar server side language as a beginning, and progress from there.

Comment: @csgomovie This is not a recruitment site, this is a site where questions that are asked should be answered based on what is contained in the question, not in private chats.